# Android Webview not detecting link click while Javascript is enabled in webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, webviewclient

In my application I need to detect the link click inside the webview.
I use the following code

```
web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.setWebViewClient(new VideoWebViewClient());

        web.loadUrl("http://syncquik.com/home.php");

class VideoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            System.out.println("link===="+url);
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return false;
        }
```

But `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` method is not called when  `web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`  is written. But if I don't write  `web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` then  `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` is called and link is detected.
I need both of this two, need to  enable javascript and detect the link click.
Please help me to figure out this.
Santanu

Answer (score 0):

It works on my project, maybe you should try to clean your project and try again by Project --> Clean